# PySpark MLlib Cross Validation for hyperparameter tuning a XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, xgboost

I'm trying to make a search for a xbgoost's parameters with the cross validation from PySpark's MLlib. I'm using the module from xgboost that is compatible with pyspark's dataframes SparkXGBRegressor.

My dataframe has 40 columns and 6 million rows.

When doing the fit of the data and already defining the parameters search the following error message appears. Is it because the cross validation is not compatible with the xgboost's module or the data is too large?

(Hardware capacity isn't a issue for this case)

```
from xgboost.spark import SparkXGBRegressor
xgb = SparkXGBRegressor(
features_col="features",
label_col="label",
num_workers=4
)

paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()\
.addGrid(xgb.learning_rate, \[float(v) for v in np.arange(0.01, 0.25, 0.01)\])\
.addGrid(xgb.colsample_bytree, \[float(v) for v in np.arange(0.8, 1.01, 0.1)\])\
.addGrid(xgb.subsample, \[float(v) for v in np.arange(0.5, 1.01, 0.1)\])\
.addGrid(xgb.n_estimators, \[int(v) for v in np.arange(100, 3000, 100)\])\
.addGrid(xgb.reg_alpha, \[float(v) for v in np.arange(0.01, 0.5, 0.05)\])\
.addGrid(xgb.max_depth, \[5, 10, 30, 50, 80, 100, 150\])\
.addGrid(xgb.gamma, \[int(v) for v in np.arange(0, 10, 2)\])\
.build())

mae_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="mae", labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction")
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=xgb, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=mae_evaluator, numFolds=5)
cvModel = cv.fit(df)
```

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
\<command-1695020085907756\> in \<module\>
1 # fit del cross-validator al dataset (acá es donde rompe --\> Error: "The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.")
\----\> 2 cvModel = cv.fit(df)

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/MLWorkloadsInstrumentation/\_pyspark.py in patched_method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
28             call_succeeded = False
29             try:
\---\> 30                 result = original_method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
31                 call_succeeded = True
32                 return result

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
159                 return self.copy(params).\_fit(dataset)
160             else:
\--\> 161                 return self.\_fit(dataset)
162         else:
163             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in \_fit(self, dataset)
711                         subModels\[i\]\[j\] = subModel
712
\--\> 713             \_cancel_on_failure(dataset.\_sc, self.uid, sub_task_failed, calculate_metrics)
714             # END-EDGE
715

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in \_cancel_on_failure(sc, uid, sub_task_failed, f)
94                           "issue, you should enable pyspark pinned thread mode."
95                           .format(uid))
\---\> 96             raise e
97
98     old_job_group = sc.getLocalProperty("spark.jobGroup.id")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in \_cancel_on_failure(sc, uid, sub_task_failed, f)
88     if os.environ.get("PYSPARK_PIN_THREAD", "false").lower() != "true":
89         try:
\---\> 90             return f()
91         except Exception as e:
92             warnings.warn("{} fit call failed but some spark jobs "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in wrapper(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
148
149             ipython.events.register("post_run_cell", on_cancel)
\--\> 150             return f(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
151
152         return wrapper

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in calculate_metrics()
705                     return task()
706
\--\> 707                 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(run_task, tasks):
708                     metrics\[j\] += (metric / nFolds)
709                     metrics_all\[i\]\[j\] = metric

/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in next(self, timeout)
866         if success:
867             return value
\--\> 868         raise value
869
870     __next__ = next                    # XXX

/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
123         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
124         try:
\--\> 125             result = (True, func(\*args, \*\*kwds))
126         except Exception as e:
127             if wrap_exception and func is not \_helper_reraises_exception:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in run_task(task)
703                     if sub_task_failed\[0\]:
704                         raise RuntimeError("Terminate this task because one of other task failed.")
\--\> 705                     return task()
706
707                 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(run_task, tasks):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in singleTask()
68
69     def singleTask():
\---\> 70         index, model = next(modelIter)
71         # TODO: duplicate evaluator to take extra params from input
72         #  Note: Supporting tuning params in evaluator need update method

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in __next__(self)
67                 raise StopIteration("No models remaining.")
68             self.counter += 1
\---\> 69         return index, self.fitSingleModel(index)
70
71     def next(self):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fitSingleModel(index)
124
125         def fitSingleModel(index):
\--\> 126             return estimator.fit(dataset, paramMaps\[index\])
127
128         return \_FitMultipleIterator(fitSingleModel, len(paramMaps))

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/MLWorkloadsInstrumentation/\_pyspark.py in patched_method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
28             call_succeeded = False
29             try:
\---\> 30                 result = original_method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
31                 call_succeeded = True
32                 return result

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
157         elif isinstance(params, dict):
158             if params:
\--\> 159                 return self.copy(params).\_fit(dataset)
160             else:
161                 return self.\_fit(dataset)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/spark/core.py in \_fit(self, dataset)
862             return ret\[0\], ret\[1\]
863
\--\> 864         (config, booster) = \_run_job()
865
866         result_xgb_model = self.\_convert_to_sklearn_model(

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/spark/core.py in \_run_job()
853         def \_run_job():
854             ret = (
\--\> 855                 dataset.mapInPandas(
856                     \_train_booster, schema="config string, booster string"
857                 )

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
965         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-credential passthrough clusters:
966         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
\--\> 967             sock_info = self.ctx.\_jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self.\_jrdd.rdd())
968         return list(\_load_from_socket(sock_info, self.\_jrdd_deserializer))
969

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, \*args)
1302
1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
\-\> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
1306

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(\*a, \*\*kw)
115     def deco(\*a, \*\*kw):
116         try:
\--\> 117             return f(\*a, \*\*kw)
118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER\[type\](answer\[2:\], gateway_client)
325             if answer\[1\] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
\--\> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\\n".
328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Could not recover from a failed barrier ResultStage. Most recent failure reason: Stage failed because barrier task ResultTask(640, 0) finished unsuccessfully.
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in \_read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in \_read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in \_read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2241)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:313)
    
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2913)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2854)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2854)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:2611)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3118)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1115)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1036)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost' " - this line in your error messages suggests the xgboost library is not installed. Maybe check that your python environment has the necessary library.

Answer (score 0):

your libraries are not available on the spark executors.

if run PySpark application on a cluster, refer this:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

if run on local, add this:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```